# Exporting call records with phone call recordings from Mega Call Recorder Advanced app

Tags: data-recovery, calls, mp3, call-recording, export

This is a long-shot, but I really hope someone can help.

I was using the [Mega Call Recorder Advanced](https://web.archive.org/web/20200430183310/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callrecorder.procallrecorder) Android app to record phone calls for quite some time.  Its official package name was `com.callrecorder.procallrecorder` and the developer's name was `MEGA Clip`.

Although I still have the app installed, it disappeared from the Play Store a while back.  I'm not sure why, as it worked quite well.  I did notice that its UI is very similar to many other call recording apps, and so I wonder if perhaps it was based on another project.

At this point, I have *many* GB of recorded calls stored by this now-defunct app.  The calls are stored in standard MP3 format, and the filename of each is the timestamp of the call.  *So far so good.*  The big issue is that the filenames do ***not*** indicate the phone number (or contact name)  of the caller (for incoming calls) / call recipient (for outgoing calls).  That data is visible in the app's UI, but I don't see any export function.

I want to backup all of this app's data and have the backups in a usable format.  To do that, I need to somehow have a record of which contact (or at least phone number) each recording is associated with.  Ideally, I would like the MP3 filenames themselves to include that essential information.

I'm hoping someone will have a good idea of how to proceed, or perhaps recognize the UI and know of another app that can perhaps export the data.

I have a strong hunch that there are other call recorder apps out there that are based on the same code.  Someone even wrote a review on the Google Play store noticing the same thing (see last screenshot below).  Perhaps one of those apps has a good export function and could read the data files from this app.

Here is what the app looks like (screenshots courtesy of the Google Play store), as well as other relevant screenshots:

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 1]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 2]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 3 with example call recordings]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 4]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 5]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 6]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 7]

[image: Mega Call Recorder Advanced Screenshot 8 showing About Page]

[image: Google Play store listing for Mega Call Recorder Advanced]

[image: Google Play store listing details for Mega Call Recorder Advanced]

[image: Google Play store review for Mega Call Recorder Advanced]

Comment: Does the share button allow to save to Google Drive? if yes, does it save the file(s) with the contact name?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a filename? Can you read/copy the app's database?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you for your interest, Reddy.  I don't have Google Drive installed, but the share button opens the standard share UI, so I think it would allow sharing with Google Drive.  But, unless I'm missing something (always possible!), it would require going to each recording and sharing it.  But maybe you know of a workaround for that?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio An example of a filename is `20191002154123.mp3`.  The first 8 digits look like the date and the last 6 look like the time.  Reading all the mp3 files is no problem at all.  I *think* I can also read/copy the app's database, but I haven't yet concluded if it is the entire database, or just some of the metadata that is stored by the app.

Comment: I am thinking you could try to share one or two files to your own Dropbox. Google Drive, etc and check if they are saved as with the same filename or not. Speaking about mp3, try to verify if the files' metadata don't contain any details related to your contacts.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks. Those are both great ideas, and I can't believe I didn't check the latter.  I'll check both and report back.

Answer (score 1):

The application keeps a copy of the database with calls logs in the folder where the call recordings are stored (/sdcard/CallRecorder/.db/callRecorder).

Prerequisites:

- [Python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed
- [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
- USB debugging enabled on the phone

Steps:

- Dump the folder /sdcard/CallRecorder using ADB from the

```
 adb pull /sdcard/CallRecorder
```

- Create a new Python file, "export.py", in the dumped folder, "callRecorder", with the following content:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from shutil import copyfile

con = sqlite3.connect(".db/callRecorder")

for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if ".mp3" not in filename:
      continue
   
   row = con.execute("Select * from calls where instr(filePath, "+ filename.replace('.mp3', '') +")").fetchone()
   phone_nbr = row[1]
   contact_name = row[2]
   date_time = filename.replace(".mp3", "")
   copyfile(filename, f"{phone_nbr}_{contact_name}_{date_time}.mp3")
```

Execute the Python file using Notepad++ Python interpreter or using CMD:

```
> python PATH\TO\callRecord\export.py
```

That will copy each record to the format "phoneNumber_contactName_datetime.mp3"

Comment: Oh my goodness... thank you so much! Wow, I am almost speechless with gratitude.  I'm definitely going to give this a try this weekend.  The only Python I currently have set up is a Python interpreter within Notepad++.  Do you have any idea if that will work?  If not, is there a portable version of Python I can quickly set up?  Are there any additional Python libraries I will need to get to make this work?  Thank you again for this ***amazingly helpful*** answer!

Comment: Glad if it can help! Yes it works using Notepad++ Python interpreter. No, the script does not need any additional libraries.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you test it with the current release version of the Notepad++ Python interpreter (v1.5.4) or the new v3.x alpha releases?

Comment: I followed the steps described in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1702605 to configure Notepad++ with Python. Notepad++ v7.9.3 and Python 3.9.2.

Comment: Ah! I'm glad I asked.  That's very different from what I was thinking.  Just FYI, Notepad++ has its own Python interpreter as a plugin: https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/releases  Since you didn't use that, I'll set up a full Python interpreter... it's probably about time I did that anyway.  Especially since I hang out around @SteveBarnes (I you want to make a pizza, Steve will figure out a way to write an amazing Python script to do it). :)

Comment: I didn't have enough time this past weekend to try this out, but I'm hoping to have a spare hour or two soon.  Regardless, I'm awarding you the bounty because you've been so helpful, and I'm very grateful!  I also have a feeling that your solution will work as is, or that we can make it work together with a little minor tweaking.

Comment: Many thanks for the bounty. Please don't hesitate if you have questions or any.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm working on it now!

Comment: I ran into an issue, but I'm pretty sure it's entirely on my end.  Instead of creating a lot of noise in the comments here, will you join me in chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/120033/lizard-in-a-st0rm